# Rails: Sending out mail to multiple recipients (strange formatting)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I want to send out a mailer to multiple recipients, here's what I have:

```
def teaser(customer)
    @customer = customer
    mail(to: customer.shop.email, subject: "Here's an interesting stat")
    mail(to: "admin@mysite.co", subject: "#{customer.shop.email} had an interesting stat")
  end
```

But the email I'm receiving at admin@mysite.co has very strange formatting. The email content is repeated 3 times in different formats, starting with:

```
----==_mimepart_563ad1e4c3af4_9d3f90c47cfe7c324dc Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

if your customers are in array

```
 def teaser(customers)
        customers.each do |customer|
         mail(to: customer.shop.email, subject: "Here's an interesting stat")
         mail(to: "admin@mysite.co", subject: "#{customer.shop.email} had an interesting stat")
      end      
end
```

Comment: Not really what I'm trying to solve. My issue is that my code is sending very strangely formatted emails with MIME type included in the body

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue with the MIME type info in the body of the email when trying to send a multipart email using Action Mailer to multiple recipients.  I originally had an ActiveRecord relation of customers and then tried to just loop through them to email them one at a time.

```
customers = User.where(access: "customer") 

   customers.each do |customer|
     mail to: customer.email, subject: "email subject test"  
   end
```

But I had to pass an array or comma separated list to the mailer instead which solved the issue of the MIME type info being in the email body.

```
  customers = User.where(access: "customer") 
  customers_emails = customers.map {|c| c.email}  
  mail(to: customers_emails, subject: 'testing')
```